# Is there a way to have multiple YouTube accounts have administrative access to a YouTube channel

Tags: youtube

I want to setup a YouTube channel for an organization I am in. I would like to give each officer in the organization access to the channel without sharing a password. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I can come up with is using a listserv address to create the account and sharing the password.